# Different CRC32 checksum for the same file

Tags: c++, dll, crc32

Basically, I have an application which imports a few DLLs and some Python libraries.
I did another application which calculates CRC32 for each of these files and I've added the list on my main application because I want to make it to check these files.
The problem is that sometimes the main application detects a DLL or a library modified even if it wasn't. It don't happens everytime and I am wondering why does that happens? What can determine the CRC32 checksum to differ? It's because my application loads these DLLs or is something external like viruses or anything else?

Here's the code for both main application and the application which does the CRC32 list:

```
#include "boost/crc.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/operations.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem/path.hpp"
#include "boost/progress.hpp"
#include "boost/integer.hpp"

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int CheckCRC32(LPCSTR szFileName, DWORD dwCRC32)
{
    if (!fs::exists(szFileName))
        return 1;

    DWORD dwResult = 0;
    boost::crc_32_type result;
    std::streamsize const buffer_size = 1024;
    ifstream file(szFileName, std::ios_base::binary);

    if (file)
    {
        do
        {
            char buffer[buffer_size];
            file.read(buffer, buffer_size);
            result.process_bytes(buffer, file.gcount());
        } while(file);
    }
    else
        return 1;

    dwResult = result.checksum();
    if (dwResult <= 0)
        return 1;

    if (dwResult != dwCRC32)
        return 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you have another solution for doing such things or if you have a solution for this method, please let me know.

Comment: One way to approach such a problem is to compare to an alternate implementation doing the same thing. Try using non-boost alternatives and see if it behaves the same. CrC32 functions are also around in abundance and you can find one easily to use. For file operations, just go "native" (``CreateFile(), ReadFile(), ... `` or use cstdio. If you then see the same effect, at least you know it is no funny thing coming from a funny library you used.

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/crc32.c  <<-- Think I used one like that in the past.

Comment: Loading a DLL shouldn't affect the contents on disk. Perhaps the problem is in the number you pass in for `dwCRC32`?

Comment: Is the size of those files a multiple of `buffer_size` (1024). You'd get an extra read() that would put zero bytes in the buffer, does `crc_32_type` handle this scenario?

Comment: @BitTickler the CRC generator in `boost` should be sufficient already - it's a well regarded library.

Comment: @BitTickler, i did that before using boost. Is the exactly same thing. I used `CreateFile()`, `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()`.
@MarkRansom, but if both numbers are generated by the same method and both numbers are the same type (`DWORD` - `unsigned long`) I think it shouldn't be a problem.
@Cristik, no. Files size are not multiple of `buffer_size`. And again, if they're both generated by same function with the same `buffer_size` shouldn't it put (if it does that) zero bytes in the buffer?

Comment: My tip tried to communicate the idea that if you look for oddities, you can gain information by changing something (e.g. the code you use replaced by alternatives). I intended that rather as a strategy. Even though I would never understand why people use boost for something which is 1 normal c function which is as easy to call. If you have the same effect with alternative implementations, and if you did not forget to initialize variables or such, it is time to search for other answers/questions: Do you recompile your DLLs between those runs? Something trivial like that?

Comment: ``std::streamsize const buffer_size = 1024;`` Do you only want to use the first 1024 bytes for your crc? Or are all your dlls smaller? What does ``file.read()`` do if there are more/less bytes to read than those 1024? Why not use that ``file.gcount()`` before the read and then use a ``std::vector<uint8_t> buffer; buffer.resize(file.gcount())`` instead of doing that fixed 1024 thing?

Comment: @BitTickler, `while(file);` reads and repeats until it don't have anything else to read so I don't read only the first 1024 bytes, but the whole file. Or this is supposed to do.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really trusting your 1024 bytes fixed buffer and the order of calls you chose. Either it is your intention to only use the first 1024 bytes of your files for the crc or this could already be the problem. On the other hand, if the files you crc are smaller than those 1024, it is up to the behavior of `file.read()` what happens.

Just to give you an option, here the code for a "low level" alternative. If the same crc values will be obtained with this version will depend on whether my initial crc value of 0 is "by the book" or if you need to use another start value.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

static uint32_t crc32_tab[] = {
    0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba, 0x076dc419, 0x706af48f,
    0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3, 0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
    0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91, 0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2,
    0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de, 0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
    0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec, 0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9,
    0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
    0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b, 0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c,
    0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940, 0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
    0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116, 0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423,
    0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f, 0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
    0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d, 0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106,
    0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a, 0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
    0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818, 0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d,
    0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
    0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457, 0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950,
    0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c, 0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
    0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2, 0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7,
    0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb, 0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
    0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9, 0x5005713c, 0x270241aa,
    0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086, 0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
    0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4, 0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81,
    0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad, 0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
    0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683, 0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84,
    0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8, 0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
    0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe, 0xf762575d, 0x806567cb,
    0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7, 0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
    0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e,
    0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252, 0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
    0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60, 0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55,
    0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79, 0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
    0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f, 0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28,
    0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04, 0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a, 0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f,
    0x72076785, 0x05005713, 0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
    0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242,
    0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e, 0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
    0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c, 0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69,
    0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45, 0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
    0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db, 0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc,
    0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0, 0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
    0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6, 0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693,
    0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf, 0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
    0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d
};

uint32_t
crc32(uint32_t crc, const void *buf, size_t size)
{
    const uint8_t *p = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(buf);

    crc = crc ^ ~0U;

    while (size--)
        crc = crc32_tab[(crc ^ *p++) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);

    return crc ^ ~0U;
}

bool Crc32OfFile(const char * pathToFile, uint32_t &result)
{
    bool success = false;
    HANDLE hFile = 
        ::CreateFileA
            ( pathToFile
            , GENERIC_READ
            , FILE_SHARE_READ
            , NULL
            , OPEN_EXISTING
            , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL|FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN
            , NULL
            );
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
    {
        DWORD fileSize = ::GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
        buffer.resize(fileSize);
        DWORD bytesRead = 0UL;
        if (::ReadFile(hFile, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), &bytesRead, NULL))
        {
            if (bytesRead == fileSize)
            {
                result = crc32(0UL, &buffer[0], buffer.size());
                success = true;
            }
        }
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? `basic_istream::read` has very well defined [behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) for cases when file length is less than `count` argument passed.

Comment: @n0rd This is why he finds the solution to his problem so quickly (sarcasm). He is not catching exceptions, he is not checking return values and then wonders what happens. Well he also checks DWORDs for <= 0.... My answer allows him to use this as a replacement which does not keep room for guesswork.  His 1024 sized buffer is also strange. So before shedding tears about me preferring to actually be able to see what is going on, better find the root cause for his problems in his boost application where nothing is obvious and show it in your answer ;)

Comment: You make an assumption that STL incorrectly implements `basic_istream::read`. Such assumptions are wrong in 99.9% of cases for any wide used STL implementation.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the CRC32 being used here. The CRC is a right shift (xor to lower order byte of CRC, cycle right 8 times).  It's the polynomial 0x104C11DB7 reversed and shifted right 1 bit  to 0xEDB88320. Note that the table entry at index 0x80 = 0xEDB88320 .

Comment: @n0rd I think you're missing a few 9's.

Comment: Actually I don't make that assumption. My assumption is that the author of the question is in over his head and lost control of what is going on. The minor tactical errors he does such as testing unsigned integers for negativity hint to me that it would be easier for him to have 2 local functions than using vast amounts of frameworks to get his code going. Something bites him and one way to get a grip is to reduce complexity. And as his code demonstrates, using libraries (with shady designs such as ifstream) does not shield him from running into trouble. I say: Brain dead is beautiful.

Comment: @BitTickler, I took the method from the official boost site so I think everything is ok because I haven't seen somewhere that specifies that I have to change my buffer size depending on file size. Also, I know I am checking an unsigned if it's negative... it's just a bad behavior of mine, sorry. I will give your method a try and I will answer ASAP about the results. Thank you.

Comment: @BitTickler, Done, I used your method and the both lists are identical. Exactly the same.